# EclipseLink and Sequence Generator Preallocation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have an issue I can't get my head around. In hibernate I have no problem with the following:

```
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "email-seq-gen" )
@SequenceGenerator( name="email-seq-gen", sequenceName="EMAIL_SEQ_GEN", allocationSize=500 )
```

Then in my schema.ddl I have this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMAIL_SEQ_GEN START 1 INCREMENT 500;
```

Not much to see here. Everything works as expected. However, if I switch my provider to EclipseLink I get this error:

```
The sequence named [EMAIL_SEQ_GEN] is setup incorrectly.  Its increment does not match its pre-allocation size.
```

So of course I google around and see something about EclipseLink creating a negative number if the initial value is 1 and that it should equal the allocationSize.

So, okay, so adding "initialValue=500" and updating my DDL scripts to "START 500" fixes this but now my numbering starts at 500 instead of 1. What gives? Is this an EclipseLink bug or is there something I am not understanding. I would like to generate sequences that start at 1 and have allocation sizes that are tuned to the entity (in this case 500). How would I do that with EclipseLink?

Thanks!

Another way to ask this is....given this DDL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMAIL_SEQ_GEN START 1 INCREMENT 500;
```

What is the correct way to annotate my entity to use it with EclipseLink?

If I let EclipseLink generate my DDL then this:

```
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "email-seq-gen" )
@SequenceGenerator( name="email-seq-gen", sequenceName="EMAIL_SEQ_GEN", initialValue=1, allocationSize=500 )
```

Will generate this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMAIL_SEQ_GEN INCREMENT BY 500 START WITH 500;
```

Which kind of implies that it is IMPOSSIBLE to create a DDL with a "START WITH 1" using EclipseLink.

Comment: If you go the other direction (let EclipseLink generate the DDL from your entities) what does it generate?

Comment: I editted the original post to add the answer to your question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By default entities annotated with `@SequenceGenerator` use initialValue=1 and alocationSize=50.

```
public @interface SequenceGenerator {
    /** 
     * (Optional) The value from which the sequence object 
     * is to start generating.
     */
    int initialValue() default 1;

    /**
     * (Optional) The amount to increment by when allocating 
     * sequence numbers from the sequence.
     */
    int allocationSize() default 50;
}
```

A "sequential" entity id seems to be calculated by EclipseLink with the following formula:

```
entityId = initialValue - allocationSize + INCREMENT_BY
```

or in case of using DDL:

```
entityId = START_WITH - allocationSize + INCREMENT_BY
```

Going back to your particular cases:

---

```
@SequenceGenerator( 
    name="email-seq-gen", 
    sequenceName="EMAIL_SEQ_GEN", 
    allocationSize=500
) // initialValue=1 (default)

CREATE SEQUENCE EMAIL_SEQ_GEN START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 500;
```

produces

```
entityId = 1 - 500 + 1 = -500 // EclipseLink error
```

---

```
@SequenceGenerator( 
    name="email-seq-gen", 
    sequenceName="EMAIL_SEQ_GEN", 
    initialValue=1, 
    allocationSize=500 )

CREATE SEQUENCE EMAIL_SEQ_GEN START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 500;
```

produces

```
entityId = 1 - 500 + 1 = -500 // EclipseLink error
```

---

```
@SequenceGenerator( 
    name="email-seq-gen", 
    sequenceName="EMAIL_SEQ_GEN", 
    initialValue=500, 
    allocationSize=500
)

CREATE SEQUENCE EMAIL_SEQ_GEN START WITH 500 INCREMENT BY 500;
```

produces

```
entityId = 500 - 500 + 500 = 500 // fine, but inappropriate
entityId = 500 - 500 + 1000 = 1000 // incremented by 500
entityId = 500 - 500 + 1500 = 1500 // incremented by 500
...
```

---

To meet your requirements the following one should be used:

```
@SequenceGenerator( 
    name="email-seq-gen", 
    sequenceName="EMAIL_SEQ_GEN", 
    allocationSize=500 
) // initialValue=1 (default) but 'START WITH'=500

CREATE SEQUENCE EMAIL_SEQ_GEN START WITH 500 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

produces

```
entityId = 500 - 500 + 1 = 1
entityId = 500 - 500 + 2 = 2
entityId = 500 - 500 + 3 = 3
...
```

---

An existing sequence can be removed from the underlying database with the following SQL [command](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqljdropsequence.html):

```sql
DROP SEQUENCE email_seq_gen RESTRICT;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It would be nice to know how to delete/drop created sequences. I tried several approaches but none of them are working.

Comment: @burseaner: I have added a command that drops an existsing sequence.

Comment: Creating the sequence with increment 1 is wrong. EclipseLink invokes the sequence only once per allocation-batch (in this case once for every 500 entities added in the same transaction). 

Therefore the increment must equal 500. Yes, numbers will be skipped when an allocation-batch is smaller than 500, but that's the price you pay for the efficiency thanks to fewer invocations of the sequence. 

To see the error that occurs, add two entities, then terminate the Java program, then add another entity. A java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException will occur due to a duplicate ID.

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence should start at 500 not 1.  If you start at 1, then the first nextval will only give you 1 id instead of 500.

Otherwise call nextval on the sequence after setting it up, so it gets to 501.

Is the error a warning or error?  If you just ignore it does it still work?

Comment: How does that make sense? If I write code to pool identities I get 1, 501, 1001, and so on. This is also what I get from Hibernate? If this is not the case with EclipseLink and (from googling around) it appears many have had an issue with this why don't they just fix this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I could fix the issue by adding a sentence in the schema generation: *RESTART*

**Entity definition**

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator=Secuences.PROFILES_SEQ)
@SequenceGenerator(name=Secuences.PROFILES_SEQ, sequenceName=Secuences.PROFILES_SEQ, allocationSize=25)
@Column( name = "id" )
private Long internalId;
```

**SQL schema initialization**

```
-- create sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE PROFILES_SEQ START WITH 1;

-- use sequence to set values in column
UPDATE public.cc_user_profile SET id = nextval('PROFILES_SEQ');

-- update sequence
ALTER SEQUENCE PROFILES_SEQ INCREMENT BY 25 START WITH 25;
ALTER SEQUENCE PROFILES_SEQ RESTART;
```

Hope it helps someone.