# Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" in derby on DROP SEQUENCE statement

Tags: sql, derby

Some sequences were created because of the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474046/eclipselink-and-sequence-generator-preallocation/20267392?noredirect=1#comment40992360_20267392). To keep everything clean I tried to delete them with the command `DROP SEQUENCE seqname;`. It produces me the following message:

> Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "" at line 1, column 20.
>   Line 1, column 1
>   Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.

I guess it is because I work on Windows machine which has different EOF marker. But how to solve the problem in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several trials the solution is `DROP SEQUENCE sequence_name RESTRICT` which was found [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqljdropsequence.html). Adding `RESTRICT` to the SQL statement solves the problem