# Alter sequence in H2

Tags: java, eclipselink, h2, liquibase

I'm using Postgres database in production and H2 for tests.
I want to create a new sequence for an existing table - so in Liquibase I wrote this:

```
<changeSet id="Add sequence for BOOKS" author="library">
    <createSequence sequenceName="BOOKS_SEQ" incrementBy="500" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

My Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "BOOKS_SEQ", allocationSize = 500)
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "BOOKS_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
        private Author author;
...

}
```

Now, since I already have entities in this table (with Ids from the last sequence I used), I need to set the current value of this sequence accordingly.
For that matter I wrote:

```
<changeSet id="Alter sequence for BOOKS" author="library">
    <sql dbms="postgresql">select setval('BOOKS_SEQ', (select nextval('OLD_SEQUENCE_UID')))</sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="Add default value to BOOKS.ID" author="library">
    <addDefaultValue tableName="BOOKS" columnName="ID" defaultValueSequenceNext="BOOKS_SEQ"/>
</changeSet>
```

In Postgres (production), it seems to work just fine - but in H2 I get an error message "The sequence named [BOOKS_SEQ] is setup incorrectly.  Its increment does not match its pre-allocation size".

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474046/eclipselink-and-sequence-generator-preallocation) - I need to set the start_value (or current value) to something greater than 500 - but I can't figure out how this can be [done in H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_sequence).

So my question is: How can I set the current value of a sequence in H2?

Answer (score 23):

Have you tried with this?

```
alter sequence <your_sequence_name> restart with <next_value>
```

For example:

```
alter sequence BOOKS_SEQ restart with 500
```

When I run the above command, I have BOOKS_SEQ set its current value to 499 (so the next value will be 500).