# H2 information shema not available verision 2. And more

Tags: java, h2

Am trying to retreive all the list of sequences from information-shema.sequences that work on H2 1.4 but since upgrade 2. Or plus it’s no longer possible.
Any other way to reset all sequences?

Select sequence_name from information_schema.sequences

Comment: The system tables schema you want to use is `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, not `INFORMATION-SHEMA`. I have not tried your specific query, however. See [here](https://www.h2database.com/html/systemtables.html) for system tables documentation.

Comment: "_reset all sequences_": If you want to reset a sequence, take a look at [Alter sequence in H2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41100306/12567365)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reset"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restart all sequences with a single command, but you can construct a list of such commands and execute them all at once:

```java
Statement s = …;
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT LISTAGG('ALTER SEQUENCE '"
        + " || QUOTE_IDENT(SEQUENCE_SCHEMA) || '.'  || QUOTE_IDENT(SEQUENCE_NAME)"
        + " || ' RESTART', '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)"
        + " FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES");
rs.next();
s.execute(rs.getString(1));
```

---

Actually there are only few valid use cases for sequences, usually you should use **identity columns** instead of them. [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#truncate_table) command has `RESTART IDENTITY` clause, so it is possible to remove all data from a table with identity column and reset its generator.

Answer (score 0):

## Spelled: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES`

You said:

> retreive all the list of sequences from information-shema.sequences

You misspelled the schema name: hyphen rather than underscore, and missing a `c`.

```java
// Query for all sequences.
String sql =
        """
        SELECT *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES  
        ;
        """;
```

Here is a complete example app to query that table.

```java
package work.basil.example.h2;

import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        DataSource dataSource = this.configureDataSource();
        this.configureDatabase( dataSource );
        this.dumpSequenceMetadata( dataSource );
    }

    private DataSource configureDataSource ( )
    {
        org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource ds = new org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource();  // Implementation of `DataSource` bundled with H2. You may choose to use some other implementation.
        ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:bogus;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;" );
        ds.setUser( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
        ds.setDescription( "An example database for accessing metadata on sequences." );
        return ds;
    }

    private void configureDatabase ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        // Add a few rows to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES table.
        String sql =
                """
                CREATE SEQUENCE employee_number_ 
                ;
                CREATE SEQUENCE invoice_number_ START WITH 100
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()
        )
        {

            System.out.println( "INFO - Running `configureDatabase` method." );
            stmt.executeUpdate( sql );
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    private void dumpSequenceMetadata ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        // Query for all sequences.
        String sql =
                """
                SELECT *
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES  
                ;
                """;
        try
                (
                        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                        Statement statement = conn.createStatement() ;
                )
        {
            try (
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( sql ) ;
            )
            {
                // The table structure of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES is documented here:
                // http://h2database.com/html/systemtables.html#information_schema_sequences
                // Only a few of the columns are used here.
                record Sequence( String catalog , String schema , String name , String dataType , long startValue , long baseValue ) { }
                while ( resultSet.next() )
                {
                    Sequence sequence = new Sequence(
                            resultSet.getString( "SEQUENCE_CATALOG" ) ,
                            resultSet.getString( "SEQUENCE_SCHEMA" ) ,
                            resultSet.getString( "SEQUENCE_NAME" ) ,
                            resultSet.getString( "DATA_TYPE" ) ,
                            resultSet.getLong( "START_VALUE" ) ,
                            resultSet.getLong( "BASE_VALUE" )
                    );
                    // Dump each INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES row.
                    System.out.println( "sequence = " + sequence );
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

When run.

```
sequence = Sequence[catalog=BOGUS, schema=PUBLIC, name=EMPLOYEE_NUMBER_, dataType=BIGINT, startValue=1, baseValue=1]
sequence = Sequence[catalog=BOGUS, schema=PUBLIC, name=INVOICE_NUMBER_, dataType=BIGINT, startValue=100, baseValue=100]
```

## `ALTER SEQUENCE`

You said:

> reset all sequences

You neglected to specify exactly what you mean by "reset".

H2 provides the [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_sequence) command to change [some sequence options](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_sequence_option).

See also this Question, [*Alter sequence in H2.*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41100306/642706)

Beware of transactions, as the documentation says "rolling back this command has no effect".